# argmax() returns int index instead of datetime

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm going through some historical stock data with pandas datareader on a jupyter notebook and, when using the argmax() function to get the date of a certain spike in the data, I'm getting a `numpy.int64` object, even though the indexes are `datetime` objects.

Here's the code:

```
start = datetime(2012, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
src= 'yahoo'
ford = web.DataReader('F', src, start, end)
```

Now, when I call `type(ford.index)`, I get the expected result:

`datetimes.DatetimeIndex`

But when I call `ford['Volume'].argmax()` I get an integer index:

`493`

instead of the expected:

`'2013-12-18'`.

What I'm I doing wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: You aren't reading the docs? Why do you assume argmax will do anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `idxmax`

```
ford['Volume'].idxmax()
```

Or fix your output with

```
ford.index[ford['Volume'].argmax()]
```

Comment: Thanks!! That solved it. Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: @zetoichi argmax return the position , idxmax return the index ~

Comment: @zetoichi. That is literally the purpose of argmax